# Cómo hacer saltos de línea en una redirección de la salida de un programa hasta un archivo? (BATCH)

Tags: windows, batch

Estoy redireccionando la salida de un programa a un archivo de la siguiente forma.

**programa.exe >> salida.txt**

El programa en la consola me da esta salida (cada string en una línea diferente).

String1

String2

String3

String4

Pero cuando hago la redireción al archivo me sale sin saltos de línea y todo junto.

String1String2String3String4....

¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de hacer que en el archivo aparezca igual que en la consola? Es decir, que después de cada String aparezca un salto de línea.

NOTA: Todas las salidas son de una única ejecución del programa.

Comment: no se como se hace en windows. En linux puedes modificar la variable de entorno IFS indicando un salto de linea, de esa manera todas las salidas que tengan un fin de linea se cambian por el salto. Podria ser que en windows se pueda definir esa variable (u otra parecida) para solucionar lo que necesitas?

Comment: Es posible que sí que haya un nuevo salto de línea, pero el editor que usas no lo detecte: En windows, muchos editores consideran una nueva línea cuando encuentran \r\n, mientras que en el resto de sistemas es \n. Si usas Notepad++, por ejemplo, eso es configurable

Comment: Pues no lo sé **jakala,** buscaré en google a ver si hay algún equivalente en windows a esa variable de entorno... Comentaré por aquí si encontre algo o no... Gracias por responder!!

Comment: **Pablo Lozano** Miraré con Notepad++ también y veré sus opciones... aunque creo que no ese el caso... pero lo cometo por aqui en  breves... gracias a ti también!!

Comment: **Pablo Lozano** Tienes razón... ese era el problema... Con Notepad++ si se ve en lineas diferentes... :-)  Muchas gracias!! ... A ver si ahora me no me da problemas porque tengo que escribir un programa en c++ para leer esos datos y los iba a leer línea por línea...  Como le pongo un like a tu respuesta? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Parece que en el programa.exe, estás imprimiendo únicamente `\n`. ¿Puedes comprobarlo?

> Si es así, debes imprimir en "programa.exe" un `\r\n` en cada final de línea.

Windows y Linux tienen diferentes finales de línea reconocidos.

Mientras Linux sólo necesita `\n`, windows necesita `\r\n`

Seguramente por esto no te funciona.

Comment: Si, ese era el problema... tuve que mirarlo con notepad++ para verlo bien... y no, m puedo modificar "programa.exe" no lo hice yo y no tengo su código... pero puede leer correctamente la salida desde el archivo con un programa que hice en c++ para computar esos datos que era mi objetivo principal, así que al final solo era un problema visual. Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

Prueba esto:

logPrograma.bat

```
@programa.exe
@echo.
```

y lo llamas con

```
logPrograma.bat >> salida.txt
```

Comment: Lo probaré!! A lo mejor así lo puedo ver con el Notepad de windows también!! Gracias!!